# How to convert to best prefix using js-quantities?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a value of `1200000 mm' and I wan't to have a method which automatically transfers to the best prefix like:

```
import Qty from 'js-quantities'

const qty = new Qty(1200000, 'mm').toBest()
// now set to 1.2, 'km' same as doing to('km') directly
```

Is this possible anyhow?

Or how can I get the ordered list of units with prefixes for the given unit to do it myself?

Comment: "Best" is subjective of course, but you could step through the metric prefixes, dividing by 1000 every time, until you got a format you liked.

Comment: Most likely a recursive call until `quantity/1000` < 1 would suit you, but you'd have to create an object map to keep a hold of the unit

Comment: But how can I get the list of possible prefixes for any unit. Like meter should also support cm which sometimes can be best, The best is a small value > 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small example of a recursive process with a unit map that divides by 1000 until it's reached the optim

```js
function toBest(num, unit) {
    const map = {
        "mm" : "m",
        "m" : "km",
        "km" : "km"
    };
    let recurse = false;
    let nextUnit = unit;
    if ((num/1000) >= 1) {
        num = (num / 1000);
        nextUnit = map[unit];
        recurse = true;
    }
    if (recurse) {
        return toBest(num, nextUnit)
    } else {
        return num+" "+unit;
    }
}

console.log(toBest(1000, "mm"));
console.log(toBest(10000000, "mm"));
console.log(toBest(47243278423, "m"));
console.log(toBest(1000000, "mm"));
console.log(toBest(999999, "mm"));
console.log(toBest(2, "mm"));
```

Now, to expand on this, you said you may want cm to m, or maybe even km to dm. This is where the object map gets tricky. You'll have to explicitly define the divisor for every possible conversion you want.

```
const map = {
    "mm" : {
        "to" : "cm",
        "divisor" : 10
    },
    "km" : {
        "to" : "dm",
        "divisor" : .0001
    },
}
```

Now your loop gets more if/else checky, but the recursive logic should hold.

Answer (score 0):

I did a further research and found another library, which works better. So I changed s-quantities`against`convert-units` which works great but has fewer supported units (at the moment). But the definition files are better structured and I may add some units to it later.

```
import convert from 'convert-units'

// to check if unit is supported
try {
  convert().from(unit)
} catch  { ... }

// to convert unit
const valueInMeter = convert(1200000).from('mm').to('m')

// and finally the best unit
const best = convert(1200000).from('mm').toBest()
// best.val = 1.2
// best.unit = 'km'
```

See more about this library at https://github.com/ben-ng/convert-units